# Porque a renderização está ocorrendo de maneira desordenada mesmo usando async / await?

Tags: react, typescript

Estou usando React e TypeScript.
A aplicação tem o objetivo de gravar agendamentos.

No *onChange()* da data selecionado pelo usuário, chamo a função *handleChangeData()*, nela disparo a atualização da data pelo *setStateData()*.
Na sequencia chamo outra função async *buscarHorarios()* (descrevo suas funcionalidades mais abaixo).
Após isso, executo atravéz de um *setShowHorarios()* a atualização da variável *showHorarios* que uso para controlar a exibição dos horários na renderização.

Essa função ***handleChangeData()*** está assim:

```
  function handleChangeData(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    let data = e.target.value;
    
    setStateData(data);
    buscarHorarios(data);
    setShowHorarios(true);  
  }
```

Na função *buscarHorarios()* chamo outras duas funções também async, primeiro a *buscarAgendamentosNaData()* que faz uma consulta ao banco via api e devolve os horários já reservados na data recebida como parâmetro. Depois, chamo a segunda função async *atualizarHorariosDisponiveis()* que atualiza os horários tornando indisponíveis aqueles que já estão reservados.
A seguir a transcrição da função ***buscarHorarios()***:

```
  async function buscarHorarios(data: string) {
    buscarAgendamentosNaData(data);
    atualizarHorariosDisponiveis();
  }
```

A função async ***buscarAgendamentosNaData()*** conforme digo, consulta via api o banco de dados, e está assim:

```
  async function buscarAgendamentosNaData(data: string) {
    const response = await api.get('agendamentos', {
      params: { 
        data_agend: data,
        organizacao_agend: state.organizacao_atd,
      }
    });
    setAgendamentosNaData(response.data); 
  }
```

Já a async *atualizarHorariosDisponiveis()*, percorre o objeto array de horários, atualizando o objeto *horarios[]* com o objeto de horários padrões para evitar trabalhar com lixos de buscas anteriores. Depois em um map, verifica se já existe reserva do horário lido, setando a propriedade **disponível="N"** e efetuando o return para atualizar o elemento no objeto array *horarios[]*.
Assim está ***atualizarHorariosDisponiveis()***:

```
  async function atualizarHorariosDisponiveis() {
    horarios.map((horario, index) => {
      horario.disponivel = 'S'; 
      agendamentosNaData.map((agendamento: Agendamento) => { 
        if(horario.hora === agendamento.hora_agend) {
          horario.disponivel = 'N'; 
        }
        return horario;
      });
    });
  }
```

O objeto array *horariospadroes* contém apenas a propriedade "hora" e "disponível" que são passados à um objeto visto como global, como a seguir (resumido):

```
const horariospadroes = [
  { hora: '08:00', disponivel: "S"},
  { hora: '08:30', disponivel: "S"},
  ...
  { hora: '17:00', disponivel: "S"},
  { hora: '17:30', disponivel: "S"}
]  

let horarios = horariospadroes;
```

Ocorre que os horários renderizados são apresentados sempre em relação à uma data selecionada anteriomente.
Exemplo:
Se seleciono a data 11/07/2021 renderiza todas os horários com meu vetor original, conforme o padrão acima.
Se Troco a data para 12/07/2021 renderiza o conteúdo de horários, só que apresenta os dados que deveriam ter sido apresentados na data selecionada antes, que foi 11/07/2021.
E assim sucessivamente.

Acredito que seja uma execução fora de ordem mas não consegui identificar as razões.

**Como isso pode ocorrer** se as chamadas estão sempre com async, async / await, ou seja, primeiro deve esperar a conclusão de um processo para na sequencia executar as instruções seguintes?

**Este é o tratamento correto para essa situação?**
Não consegui identificar o problema. Podem por favor me ajudar?

Toda ajuda é bem vinda.

A seguir, apresento para entendimento do "todo" de forma resumida a estrutura do código como está:

```
import React, { FormEvent, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
...

const horariospadroes = [
  { hora: '08:00', disponivel: "S"},
  { hora: '08:30', disponivel: "S"},
  ...
  { hora: '17:00', disponivel: "S"},
  { hora: '17:30', disponivel: "S"}
]  
let horarios = horariospadroes;

export interface Horario {
  hora: string;
  disponivel: string;
}

interface AtendimentoItemProps {  atendimento: Atendimento; }

export interface Agendamento {  ...omitido... }

const CadastroAgendamento: React.FC<AtendimentoItemProps> = ({atendimento}) => {
  const history = useHistory();  
  const { state } = useLocation<Atendimento>();
  const [showHorarios, setShowHorarios] = React.useState(false);  
  ...
  const [agendamentosNaData, setAgendamentosNaData] = useState([]); 

  // não sei porque, a primeira execução sempre retorna vazio, então força a primeira execução com data vazia
  useEffect(() => {
    buscarAgendamentosNaData('1900-01-01');
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    buscarHorarios('1900-01-01');
  }, []);

  async function buscarHorarios(data: string) {
    buscarAgendamentosNaData(data);
    atualizarHorariosDisponiveis();
  }  

  async function buscarAgendamentosNaData(data: string) {
    const response = await api.get('agendamentos', {
      params: { 
        data_agend: data,
        organizacao_agend: state.organizacao_atd,
      }
    });
    setAgendamentosNaData(response.data); 
  }

  async function atualizarHorariosDisponiveis() {
    let horario = horariospadroes;
    horario.map((horario, index) => {
      agendamentosNaData.map((agendamento: Agendamento) => { 
        if(horario.hora === agendamento.hora_agend) {
          horario.disponivel = 'N'; 
        }
        return horario;
      });
    });
  }

  interface HorariosProps {...omitido...}

  const Horarios: React.FC<HorariosProps> = (props) => {
    let horarioRenderizado;
    if (props.disponivel==="S"){
      horarioRenderizado = 
        <div className="horario-item" style={{ color:"#FFFFFF" }} onClick={(e) => { setHoraAgend( props.hora ) }} >
          {props.hora}
        </div>;
    } else {
      horarioRenderizado = 
        <div style={{ color:"#FFFFFF", background:"#C7B7B7", cursor:"none", textDecoration:"line-through" }} className="horario-item" >
          {props.hora}
        </div>;
    }
  
    return(
      <div>
        { horarioRenderizado }
      </div>  
    );
  }
  
  function handleIncluirAgendamento(e: FormEvent ) { ... omitido ...  }

  function handleChangeData(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    let data = e.target.value;
    setStateData(data);
    buscarHorarios(data);
    setShowHorarios(true); 
  }
    
  function ShowHorariosDisponiveis(props: any) {
    return(
      props.showHorarios ? 
      <div className="horario-container">
        {horarios.map((horario) => {
            return <Horarios hora={horario.hora} disponivel={horario.disponivel} />;
          })}
      </div> 
      : 
      null 
    );
  }

  return (
    <div id="cadastro-agendamento" className="container-cadastroagendamento">
      <Cabecalho />
      <main className="container-cadastroagendamento">
        <form onSubmit={handleIncluirAgendamento}>
          <fieldset className="container-form">

            <ShowHorariosDisponiveis showHorarios={showHorarios}/>

            <div className="input-block">
              <br></br>
              <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" style={{ borderRadius: 50 }} className="botao" >
                  Confirmar
                </Button>
              </ThemeProvider>
            </div>

          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CadastroAgendamento;
```

Comment: tem assim async function mas, no seu corpo não tem await já é um problema sobre o sincronismo, toda função async tem algo a ser resolvido que precisa aguardar com await ... O código no geral tem problemas e por isso dos erros e atualizações seguindo sequencias não previstas

Comment: você sabe utilizar `async/await`, o seu código aparentemente em alguns pontos não precisa desse recurso!

Comment: São meus primeiros passos com React, poderiam me indicar onde está errado e algum exemplo da forma correta de se usar?

Comment: tem muitas alterações, acho primeiro deveria estudar, tipo `atualizarHorariosDisponiveis` não precisa de async ... na minha visão entendeu, eu entendo o seu inicio, mas, precisa antes estudar javascript primeiro . Ok!